# Passing a movable object

Tags: c++

Reading an answer in SO, he passed a `vector` with `move`. I thought the correct way is to pass it simple without using `move`:

```
class B
{
    std::vector<T> data;

public:
    B(std::vector<T> p) : data(std::move(p)) {}
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                     ?
};
```

The second way is:

```
class B
{
    std::vector<T> data;

public:
    B(std::vector<T> p) : data(p) {}
};
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: Second one makes two copies

Comment: If you need copy-semantics, use copy-semantics. If you need move-semantics use move-semantics. There is no more correct solution.

Comment: You need move, coz p is lvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function argument is already taken by value, so a copy will already have been made. The local object `p` is unquestioningly yours and yours alone, so you can move from it unconditionally.

The beauty of taking the argument by value is that it works for both lvalues and rvalues: For lvalues you make a genuine copy, since there's nothing else you can do, but for rvalues the function argument itself can be constructed by moving, so there's only one expensive construction happening ever, and everything else is moved.

Answer (score 2):

When you construct an object from an lvalue, it will be copied. When you construct an object from a non-`const` rvalue it can be moved (whether it will be moved depends on the class having a move constructor). In the context of your constructor, `p` is clearly a lvalue: it has a name. However, it is a local variable and about to go away, i.e., it is save to move from it: `std::move(p)` makes the object appear as if it is an rvalue: in this context, `std::move()`ing the value is the right way to go.

Note that the recommendations are different if you return an object: a local value returned in a `return` statement is automatically moved from. Using `std::move()` would just reinforce the statement but would also inhibit the possibility of eliding the copy/move entirely. In your constructor the copy/move cannot be elided because copy elision only works with temporary objects or with local objects in `return` statements.

```
T f() {
    T local;
    return local; // good: elided, moved, or copied in this order of preference
}
T g() {
    T local;
    return std::move(local); // bad: can't be elided and will be moved or copied
}
```